# how to get response header in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, http

Hey i have implemented an api which is a GET request 
now what i want is Response Header values but only some of them are showing in the api reponse but in network tab every value is showing
i dont know what is the problem

**this is my Http service**

```
pendingResultData(payload: Payload, headerConfig?: {}) {
const params = payload
  ? {
    type: payload.type,
    data_scopes: payload.data_scopes,
    observe: 'response',
    ...headerConfig
  }
  : { observe: 'response', ...headerConfig };
const reqUrl = '/api/data_capture';
return this.timerService.timer(this.httpService.getFullResponse(reqUrl, params));
}
```

**this is my  interceptor**

```
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
this.idToken = this.authService.getAccessToken() || '';
// cloning original request and set/add new headers
const authReq = req.clone({
  headers: this.idToken
    ? req.headers
      .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.idToken}`)
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .set("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "*")
    : req.headers,
  params: req.params
});
return next.handle(authReq);
}
```

now the headers are coming in response header you can see in Screen shot

[image: Netwrok Tab]

i want total, current-page, per-page but headers i am getting in api response are

```
headers: "content-length: 194
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"
```

i wanna know am i doing something wrong and if this a backend problem or not?
any help?
thanks

Comment: what does this do? `this.timerService.timer(this.httpService.getFullResponse(reqUrl, params));`

Comment: @Mustahsan timerService just adds the delay in response and getFullResponse is a get request with param and  to get headers in response too

Answer (score 1):

You can access these by user `response.headers.get()` method. e.g:

```
this.httpService.getFullResponse(reqUrl, params).subscribe(response=> {
  console.log(response.headers.get('per-page'));
});
```

Comment: is it been showing in chrome network tab? or they are null there too?

Comment: they are showing in network tab but in response no custom headers

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to add your custom headers to "access-control-expose-headers" in the backend response. In your screenshot from above it looks that their are not in the list.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5237#issuecomment-441081290